# Formatting questions/answers with a scroll bar

Tags: support, markdown, horizontal-scroll-bar

My questions/answers have code blocks and lengthy ones. I would like to have horizontal scroll bars instead of wrapping the text. What kind of format I should do to achieve this?

Comment: I've clicked through *many* of your answers and questions, and could not find a single one which does imply that you *do not know* how code formatting works. So, what's the question here?

Comment: Just go thro my answeer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223583/passing-a-parameter-from-ajax-to-jsp-page/9225071#9225071. Here I would like to have single line for code blocks with horizontal scroll bar. The code block `<input type='hidden' value='<%=dynamicallyCreatedURL%>' id='dynamicallyCreatedURL'/>` wrapped, Instead I would like to have in single line with scroll bar. Is it Possible?

Comment: @Bobby - you're too fast for me...

Comment: What gave you the impression that the [four-space-indentation](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) does not work for single lines?

Comment: @Bobby - That was weird though - I read the question.  But by the time I clicked edit I was already editing YOUR revision...

Comment: @Lix: Yeah, welcome in the fantastic world of ***automatic brain- and thought-reading edits***. It's a feature Jeff wrote tonight, the moment Stack Overflow scans ***your brain*** with it's ***mind*** and applies the changes you want to make.

Comment: @Bobby - What a genius idea!  You should take a look at the [foot massage user-script](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/000/554/facepalm.jpg) too!

Comment: Be warned that there are people who will deliberately edit your code back to a readable (i.e. without scrolling) form...

Comment: @Benjol As they should, big horizontal scrollbars are very annoying. Can't read the question without scrolling -_-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you mean code blocks - *as displayed with lines starting at four or more spaces* - like this:

```
System.out.println("1. My questions/answers have code blocks and lengthy ones, I would like to have horizontal scroll bars instead of wraping the text. What kind of format I should do to achive this. Please help me. 2. My questions/answers have code blocks and lengthy ones, I would like to have horizontal scroll bars instead of wraping the text. What kind of format I should do to achive this. Please help me. 3. My questions/answers have code blocks and lengthy ones, I would like to have horizontal scroll bars instead of wraping the text. What kind of format I should do to achive this. Please help me. 4. Have to admit, I am not very good at formatting my code. 5. some people say that long lines make it harder to analyse side-by-side diffs at code review but I don't care."
```

...then I would recommend to learn how to [improve formatting](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html#262) of your code.

Comment: Wow... I never thought of the reviewing nightmares this creates... [Yuck](http://ragegenerator.com/images/ragebuilder-faces/Stupidity/OhGodWhy.png)

Comment: @Lix: If you think that's bad, have a [look at the abuse in the sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox). ;)

Comment: Yes - That's a madhouse :P

Comment: @Lix: And you only see the 'lite' version, wait until you reach 10k. ;P

Comment: @Bobby - 10k on **meta**???  I've been here for 60days overall! Does my name tag say "Lix's Reputation Bordello"???

Comment: @Lix: No...but maybe you'd receive more upvotes with that name. ;P

Comment: @Bobby - I was thinking more on the lines of `Jeff9 Waffle The Lizzard  Balpha's Reputation Gravell and John Skeet souvenirs emporium`

Comment: @Lix: Awesome! :D

Comment: @Lix, I like that second one

Answer (score 5):

If you are posting huge blocks of code - perhaps you are posting too much code.  One should only include the portions of the code that he/she feels are relevant to the problem.
One thing to note is that you can use the four spaces in front of the line to disable the text wrapping feature :

( [image]
 alert! )

```
That way you can write really long sentences and/or lines of code while still staying on the same line! <br/> No linebreaks here! <br/> You will never know if there is anything important at the end of the line but you just have to keep scrolling!! This is extremely annoying (as you probably have notices by now ;) So leave the text wrapping alone cause it will keep us all sane.
```

Check out the 
[FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).  Specifically the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) section - I think you'll be able to find ALL the examples of what is possible there :P

In case it was not clear - it's a little bit annoying to have to scroll through text/code like that.  Unless it is **explicitly required** ( love to get some examples if there are some ), then single long lines of text or code should be used sparingly.